# how to change the color scale for each graph with facet_wrap and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I have a question about facet_wrap() in ggplot2.
I am trying to make a graph that looks like this. I attach an example image 1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET09N.png)

In image 1 it can be seen that there are two maps and each one has its legend and color scale. I would like to be able to do this with ggplot and the facet_wrap() function.

My problem is that because the data in the dataframe is very different, they have a lot of amplitude for each map, when plotting the scale it does not allow me to visualize it the way I want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdVdA.png)

```
ggplot(dataframe,mapping=aes(x=lon,x=lat))+
   geom_contour_fill((aes(z=hgt,fill=stat(level)))+
   geom_contour(aes(z=hgt),color="black",size=0.2)+
   scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrBr",direction = 1,super=ScaleDiscretised)+
   mi_mapa+
   coord_quickmap(xlim = range(dataframe$lon),ylim=range(dataframe$lat),expand = FALSE)+
   facet_wrap(~nombre_nivel,scales="free", ncol =2) +
   labs(x="Longitud",y="Latitud",fill="altura",title = "campos")
```

my dataframe has a shape like this. Where the facets are determined by the level variable. In this case the dataframe has another variable which is temp instead of hgt, but it's just another name.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAxTj.png)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the example figure is facetted, but facet may have been used for the strip titles. Would there be a reason why compositing two seperate plots with e.g. {patchwork} wouldn't work?

Comment: I agree, it looks like the original is actually two separate plots, each having a single facet. This is how there are two color scales, but also two e.g. titles. And I think that approach is the easiest to get what you want.

Comment: Hi. The example that I presented (image 1) is a graph that I made by hand. In other words, I generated an image and then another, I cut them out in paint with a screenshot. I would like my graph to be like this (like image 1), but to do it with code.

Comment: @Gerlielbecario as the image is made by pasting the two parts from two sources then my answer is giving you exactly what yoy want. It prints two ggplots on the canvas of `grid`. The two viewports will be the left and right parts of this canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've faced the alike problem building the two parts of the single map with two different scales. I found the package `grid` useful.

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
print(myggplot, vp = specifiedviewport)
```

In my case I built the first `p <- ggplot()` than adjusted `p2 <- p + ...`
with printing the two ggplots (`p` and `p2`) in two viewports. You can newly construct `p2` with individual scale and print it in the grid. You can find useful information
[here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/).

Comment: Hello, sorry I couldn't answer these days. Thank you I was reading your message and the link on the grid documentation and it does exactly what I need. This student thanks you hahahaha

Comment: @Gerlielbecario At stackowerflow if the answer does what you want you are expected to accept it by ticking ✓